# Are でしかない and にすぎない synonymous? Or is there some connotation?

Tags: grammar

For example:

> 事故にあって、あなたが無事なら、心配いらない。車は車でしかないよ。

can be swapped for

> 事故にあって、あなたが無事なら、心配いらない。車は車にすぎない。

without changing the meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, 車は車**でしかない** can be swapped for 車は車**にすぎない** without changing the meaning.

In the given context, they have the same meaning as "The car is only a car.", which implies "The car is only a car unlike your life. No matter how damaged it gets, it can be compensated by such as repairing it or replacing it with a new one."

---

## EDIT

> ...are there instances where swapping is impossible?

Very few, but certainly there are.
There is a corpus named "少納言｛しょうなごん｝" [here](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/), which collected a vast number of actual Japanese sentences. In this corpus, I searched for sentence examples with "でしかない" as a keyword, and I examined whether they can be replaced with "にすぎない".
In many cases, I found they could be, but I found an example that couldn't be replaced with にすぎない, which is shown below.

> だが、自分の老後を頼れるのは朔太郎｛さくたろう｝**でしかない**と、信じていた。

This sentence could be rewritten as:
だが、自分の老後を頼れるのは朔太郎｛さくたろう｝**を除いて（他｛ほか｝に）いない**と、信じていた。
*However, I believed that there was no one except Sakutaro whom I could depend on for the life of my old age.*

Comment: I understand, are there instances where swapping is  impossible?

Comment: @Chocolate: いつもありがとうございます。その都度もう少し勉強しなければと思いながらも勉強しております。

Comment: @personanongrata: I answered in my EDIT.

Comment: @Chocolate: またも助けていただきました。ありがとうございます。few（数）とlittle（量）を辞書で見ながら違う方を選んでいるとは...。質問がare there などのでthere are と回答するのが穏当とは思いながらも、一つしか例が見つかりませんでしたので...。やはり顧客優先ですね。

Comment: 直前にvery fewがあるので・・・　fewが複数扱いなので are にしました・・