# Can I use ～にすぎない for something not getting past some (low) level?

Tags: meaning

So the ～にすぎない grammar is used when you mean something doesn't get past some (high) level.
Can I use it to mean something doesn't get too low, in a phrase such as 「自分の国の冬は、低温が15度に過ぎない。」? (meaning, the minimum temperature never goes under 15 degrees)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be asking whether or not `に過ぎない` can be naturally used to express the *lower bound* of something. The answer to this is no, for multiple reasons.

First of all, when talking about exceeding/going past something specific, you want `を過ぎる`, but even then `過ぎる` means something closer to English's `go past` than it does `exceed`. You can see examples [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%92%E9%81%8E%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B), but it's most often used for passing by or through something, either temporally (such as passing your peak) or physically (such as passing a car). The closest example I can find to what you are trying to do is a webpage [here](https://www.jalan.net/yad355902/blog/entry0001028385.html?targetPgId=USW3512) that says `マイナス５度を過ぎると。。。`, but I am fairly certain this only works because the negative number is in some sense growing in size - a little like English's `get past negative 5`. `を過ぎる` cannot generally be used to talk about something decreasing or being lower.

Second of all, `に過ぎない` is a set phrase meaning something like `to be nothing more than`. This is touched on briefly [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/are-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-synonymous-or-is-there-some-connotation) and you can also see examples [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84&ref=wl), but the point is that `15度に過ぎない` doesn't mean `doesn't go past 15 degrees`, it means `a mere 15 degrees`. Note that `過ぎる` can (as you may know) also be attached to verbs and is used in several other set expressions.

All that said, for talking about a value that a temperature doesn't get higher than, I would in general use [超える](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%92%E8%B6%85%E3%81%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) which is a lot like English's `exceed`. For talking about a value that a temperature doesn't drop below, your best choice is probably [下回る](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%B8%8B%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B). [上回る](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%B8%8A%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B) is also fine in place of `超える`.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  However regarding:マイナス５度を過ぎると.  If that's supposed to mean "colder than -5 degrees", then it just sounds to me like a case of innumeracy.  Perhaps this usage is a bit like when some Americans say, if the temperature went from 40 degrees (Fahrenheit) to 80 degrees, that the temperature doubled.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the detailed answer!